# Cannot get both records with SQL/Bigquery JOINs

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've got a query that returns order details, I want information from the briisk table for deals it has found. I also want it to display orders even if the briisk table has nothing.
If I add the final line (and `flostream.briisk.master = ""`) my query only returns one result instead of two.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT orderno,ifnull(dealid,sales_rule) as DealIDCombo from flostream.orders left join  mobileheads.surveys on mobileheads.surveys.order_number = flostream.orders.externalreference) as first
INNER JOIN flostream.orders on first.orderno = flostream.orders.orderno
LEFT JOIN flostream.briisk on first.dealidcombo = flostream.briisk.uniquereference
WHERE first.orderno in (359692,359683)
//AND flostream.briisk.master = ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a `left outer join`, then you need to include filter conditions on the second table in the `on` clause.  So try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT orderno,ifnull(dealid,sales_rule) as DealIDCombo
      from flostream.orders left join
           mobileheads.surveys
           on mobileheads.surveys.order_number = flostream.orders.externalreference
     ) as first INNER JOIN
     flostream.orders
     on first.orderno = flostream.orders.orderno LEFT JOIN
        flostream.briisk
     on first.dealidcombo = flostream.briisk.uniquereference AND
        flostream.briisk.master = ""
WHERE first.orderno in (359692, 359683)
```

Conditions on the first table should go in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Gordon beat me to it by 3 seconds.  He is correct, add the and statement to the Left Join Argument.

Comment: Ooohhhh I see! I get this error: Query Failed
Error: ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey guys I think I got it, I just added all my filters into the left join and i referenced it as a alias.  LEFT JOIN (select flostream.briisk.uniquereference from flostream.briisk where flostream.briisk.master = "") as BR
     on first.dealidcombo = BR.uniquereference   Thanks!!

Comment: @NikS . . . Uggh.  I didn't realize that bigquery had that strange limitation on outer joins.  I thought only MS Access had such weirdness.